# Copy open files over network

Tags: copy, networking

Copy open files over network- I have a situation where I ahve to copy the entire contents of a user's hard disk over the remotely over the local network and silently. I am concerned about open files the user might have. Is there a free software or method that I can use to be able to copy the hard disk of the user?

Comment: Any particular environment?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Windows clients you might hack around with the [script that Tomalack posted here](http://serverfault.com/questions/119120/how-to-use-a-volume-shadow-copy-to-make-backups/119592#119592). Be aware that copying open files may give you inconsistent copies unless the application holding the file open is able to quiesce its IO and put it's files into a consistent state on demand... say, when VSS tells it that a snapshot is being initiated.

Edit: There's some more background on using VSS to create mountable volumes here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/adioltean/archive/2006/09/18/761515.aspx. Good luck finding the DOSDEV.EXE referenced in the post, though.