# Live WIM image capture?

Tags: windows-pe, imagex, wim

Is there a tool that can capture a live Server WIM image? Without having to boot the server into WinPE and use imageX. A free or commercial tool would be OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Sure, free solution: you can use [volume shadow copy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754968(WS.10).aspx) and ImageX to do this on your own.

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=C:
vssadmin list shadows
```

Then grab the shadow copy's [volume ID](https://serverfault.com/questions/119120/how-to-use-a-volume-shadow-copy-to-make-backups). (Usually looks like \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopyXX.)

```
imagex /capture \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy10\\ image.wim "Server Image"
```

Then get rid of the shadow copy.

```
vssadmin delete shadows /for=C:
```

Might want to use an exact shadow ID to delete (see the /shadow=XXX switch.)

For a solid enterprise-style solution, see [SmartDeploy](http://smartdeploy.com/).

Comment: SmartDeploy is great!  Highly recommended.

Comment: You can do this in Windows 7 as well, although `vssadmin create` doesn't exist.  It can be done with a bit of VBScript, though.  See: http://pastebin.com/uvB8KtMR

Answer (score 0):

Ghost has this functionality but for GHO not WIM images - http://altirisbe.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-use-ghost-imaging-to-create.html

Comment: This is a protected blogpost ... [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.